# next or previous syntax in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I want to compare the dates with in the consumer group with `next` or `previous` syntax  in crystal report, but the problem is when I use the `previous` syntax it is comparing with the previous group's `last record`.

For example

A

```
      start        end
 1. 12/07/2010  10/07/2013
 2. 10/08/2013  10/24/2013
 3. 10/24/2013  04/14/2014
```

B

```
 1. 03/05/2014  04/10/2014
 2. 04/10/2014  05/06/2014
 3. 05/16/2014
```

Every group's first record is get comparing with the previous group's last record. 
when using `Previous` Syntax Consumer B's first start date is getting compared with the Consumer A's End Date, which should not happen.

Comment: For all records it is behaving the same way? or for first record it is behaving the way you asked?

Comment: Every group's first record is get comparing with the previous group's last record.

Comment: Ok then what is the requirement? I dont see any wrong with the behaviour